# Not able to run example shipped with Artemis

Tags: activemq-artemis

I am trying to run an example from Artemis via the `mvn verify` command, but it is only downloading some dependencies and not stopping to download

```
   C:\apache-artemis-2.6.3-bin\apache-artemis-2.6.3\examples\features\standard\queue>mvn verify
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] -------------< org.apache.activemq.examples.broker:queue >--------------
[INFO] Building ActiveMQ Artemis JMS Queue Example 2.6.3
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
Downloading from apache.snapshots: https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/codehaus/mojo/cobertura-maven-plugin/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4:enforce (enforce-maven) @ queue ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4:enforce (enforce-java) @ queue ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-remote-resources-plugin:1.5:process (process-resource-bundles) @ queue ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ queue ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 3 resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ queue ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.17:check (default) @ queue ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- apache-rat-plugin:0.12:check (default) @ queue ---
[INFO] RAT will not execute since it is configured to be skipped via system property 'rat.skip'.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ queue ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\apache-artemis-2.6.3-bin\apache-artemis-2.6.3\examples\features\standard\queue\src\test\resources
[INFO] Copying 3 resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ queue ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test (default-test) @ queue ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ queue ---
[INFO] Building jar: C:\apache-artemis-2.6.3-bin\apache-artemis-2.6.3\examples\features\standard\queue\target\queue-2.6.3.jar
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-site-plugin:3.3:attach-descriptor (attach-descriptor) @ queue ---
[INFO]
[INFO] >>> maven-source-plugin:2.2.1:jar (attach-sources) > generate-sources @ queue >>>
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4:enforce (enforce-maven) @ queue ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4:enforce (enforce-java) @ queue ---
[INFO]
[INFO] <<< maven-source-plugin:2.2.1:jar (attach-sources) < generate-sources @ queue <<<
[INFO]
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-source-plugin:2.2.1:jar (attach-sources) @ queue ---
[INFO] Building jar: C:\apache-artemis-2.6.3-bin\apache-artemis-2.6.3\examples\features\standard\queue\target\queue-2.6.3-sources.jar
[INFO]
[INFO] >>> maven-source-plugin:2.2.1:jar (default) > generate-sources @ queue >>>
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4:enforce (enforce-maven) @ queue ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4:enforce (enforce-java) @ queue ---
[INFO]
[INFO] <<< maven-source-plugin:2.2.1:jar (default) < generate-sources @ queue <<<
[INFO]
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-source-plugin:2.2.1:jar (default) @ queue ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- dependency-check-maven:1.4.3:check (default) @ queue ---
[INFO] Skipping dependency-check
[INFO]
[INFO] --- artemis-maven-plugin:2.6.3:create (create) @ queue ---
[INFO] Local       id: local
      url: file:///C:/Users/a.subhashrao.pande/.m2/repository/
   layout: default
snapshots: [enabled => true, update => always]
 releases: [enabled => true, update => always]

[INFO] Entries.size 2
[INFO] ... key=project = MavenProject: org.apache.activemq.examples.broker:queue:2.6.3 @ C:\apache-artemis-2.6.3-bin\apache-artemis-2.6.3\examples\features\standard\queue\pom.xml
[INFO] ... key=pluginDescriptor = Component Descriptor: role: 'org.apache.maven.plugin.Mojo', implementation: 'org.apache.activemq.artemis.maven.ArtemisCLIPlugin', role hint: 'org.apache.activemq:artemis-maven-plugin:2.6.3:cli'
role: 'org.apache.maven.plugin.Mojo', implementation: 'org.apache.activemq.artemis.maven.ArtemisCreatePlugin', role hint: 'org.apache.activemq:artemis-maven-plugin:2.6.3:create'
role: 'org.apache.maven.plugin.Mojo', implementation: 'org.apache.activemq.artemis.maven.ArtemisDependencyScanPlugin', role hint: 'org.apache.activemq:artemis-maven-plugin:2.6.3:dependency-scan'
role: 'org.apache.maven.plugin.Mojo', implementation: 'org.apache.activemq.artemis.maven.ArtemisClientPlugin', role hint: 'org.apache.activemq:artemis-maven-plugin:2.6.3:runClient'
---
Executing org.apache.activemq.artemis.cli.commands.Create create --allow-anonymous --silent --force --user guest --password guest --role guest --port-offset 0 --data ./data --allow-anonymous --no-web --no-autotune --verbose C:\apache-artemis-2.6.3-bin\apache-artemis-2.6.3\examples\features\standard\queue\target\server0
Home::C:\apache-artemis-2.6.3-bin\apache-artemis-2.6.3\examples\features\standard\queue\..\..\..\.., Instance::null
Creating ActiveMQ Artemis instance at: C:\apache-artemis-2.6.3-bin\apache-artemis-2.6.3\examples\features\standard\queue\target\server0

You can now start the broker by executing:

   "C:\apache-artemis-2.6.3-bin\apache-artemis-2.6.3\examples\features\standard\queue\target\server0\bin\artemis" run

Or you can setup the broker as Windows service and run it in the background:

   "C:\apache-artemis-2.6.3-bin\apache-artemis-2.6.3\examples\features\standard\queue\target\server0\bin\artemis-service.exe" install
   "C:\apache-artemis-2.6.3-bin\apache-artemis-2.6.3\examples\features\standard\queue\target\server0\bin\artemis-service.exe" start

   To stop the windows service:
      "C:\apache-artemis-2.6.3-bin\apache-artemis-2.6.3\examples\features\standard\queue\target\server0\bin\artemis-service.exe" stop

   To uninstall the windows service
      "C:\apache-artemis-2.6.3-bin\apache-artemis-2.6.3\examples\features\standard\queue\target\server0\bin\artemis-service.exe" uninstall
[INFO] ###################################################################################################
[INFO] create-server0.sh created with commands to reproduce server0
[INFO] under C:\apache-artemis-2.6.3-bin\apache-artemis-2.6.3\examples\features\standard\queue\target
[INFO] ###################################################################################################
[INFO]
[INFO] --- artemis-maven-plugin:2.6.3:cli (start) @ queue ---
server-err:Error: There is another process using the server at C:\apache-artemis-2.6.3-bin\apache-artemis-2.6.3\examples\features\standard\queue\target\server0\lock. Cannot start the process!
Dec 21, 2018 9:36:55 AM org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.RemotingConnectionImpl bufferReceived
ERROR: AMQ214013: Failed to decode packet
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: AMQ119032: Invalid type: 1
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.PacketDecoder.decode(PacketDecoder.java:455)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.ClientPacketDecoder.decode(ClientPacketDecoder.java:67)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.ClientPacketDecoder.decode(ClientPacketDecoder.java:42)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.RemotingConnectionImpl.bufferReceived(RemotingConnectionImpl.java:368)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl$DelegatingBufferHandler.bufferReceived(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:1177)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.netty.ActiveMQChannelHandler.channelRead(ActiveMQChannelHandler.java:73)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:310)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:284)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1434)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:965)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:645)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:580)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:497)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:459)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:884)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.ActiveMQThreadFactory$1.run(ActiveMQThreadFactory.java:118)

Dec 21, 2018 9:36:55 AM org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl$DelegatingBufferHandler bufferReceived
ERROR: AMQ214031: Failed to decode buffer, disconnect immediately.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: AMQ119032: Invalid type: 1
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.RemotingConnectionImpl.bufferReceived(RemotingConnectionImpl.java:381)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl$DelegatingBufferHandler.bufferReceived(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:1177)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.netty.ActiveMQChannelHandler.channelRead(ActiveMQChannelHandler.java:73)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:310)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:284)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1434)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:965)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:645)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:580)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:497)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:459)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:884)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.ActiveMQThreadFactory$1.run(ActiveMQThreadFactory.java:118)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: AMQ119032: Invalid type: 1
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.PacketDecoder.decode(PacketDecoder.java:455)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.ClientPacketDecoder.decode(ClientPacketDecoder.java:67)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.ClientPacketDecoder.decode(ClientPacketDecoder.java:42)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.RemotingConnectionImpl.bufferReceived(RemotingConnectionImpl.java:368)
        ... 21 more

Dec 21, 2018 9:36:55 AM org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.RemotingConnectionImpl fail
WARN: AMQ212037: Connection failure has been detected: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: AMQ119032: Invalid type: 1 [code=GENERIC_EXCEPTION]
```

Comment: What do you mean by, "not stopping to download"? Can you share the full output from when you run `mvn verify`?

Comment: @JustinBertram updated the output. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an error reported that another process is using the broker:

> server-err:Error: There is another process using the server at C:\apache-artemis-2.6.3-bin\apache-artemis-2.6.3\examples\features\standard\queue\target\server0\lock. Cannot start the process!`

Make sure nothing else is using the server lock, and the example should run without a problem. I downloaded Artemis 2.6.3 and ran the `queue` example without any issues.

Comment: I tried to uninstall that but getting following message. Could you please suggest a way.

C:\apache-artemis-2.6.3-bin\apache-artemis-2.6.3\examples\features\standard\queue\target\server0\lock>cli.lock stop

The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

Comment: I tried to delete it manually but it is saying

"cannot delete it is opened in java,exe"

Comment: I tried to find it in task manager but could not able to find it. So i have extracted artemis-mq in some other drive and tried to run again. Yes and it is running fine. You are great Justin. Thanks for all your help. COuld you please suggest me what should i first start to learn Artemis MQ. I have a core java knowledge and i need to learn AMQP via artemis to for one project.